# Why when using \ref {} for equations work, but when using to reference images i get a (??) as result ?

Tags: cross-referencing

i'm using the {fei} class im my document and my preamble is pretty simple as follows

```
\documentclass[rascunho]{fei}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
```

when using the \ref{} command to call an equation as in the example below, the resut is pretty much the expected:

```
\begin{equation}
\nu_{max} \propto T \Leftrightarrow \nu_{max}=Constante_{2}.T
\label{eq4}
\end{equation}
onde, para um corpo negro, a equação (\ref{eq3})
```

[image: Result from the code above]

But when using the exact same command to call in a figure i get an error, the code go as following:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\center
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{fig15.jpg}
\label{fig15}
\end{figure}
```

[image: And thats the result when i use for figures]

Any equation that i reference works perfectly fine, but every single figure i try use the same method shows this error, i read that compiling 2 or more times might be able to fix  the issue, but i tried several times and it persists.

i'm pretty sure it must be something really simple and easy to fix, but cant find what no matter how much i try....

Comment: You need to reference a *caption*. A `figure` environment without `\caption` doesn't generate a number LaTeX can refer to. By the way you should use `\centering` rather than `\center`.

Comment: Also you should load `siunitx` and input the value of the constant as `\SI{2,898e-3}{\meter\kelvin}`

Comment: Ohh my, i have no ideia how i didn't realize it sooner, i knew it was something simple right under my nose.     
Thank you very much for your help @egreg, and sorry to take your time with such a silly question
i'm really grateful

Comment: Also you should load siunitx and input the value of the constant  as \SI{2,898e-3}{\meter\kelvin}    <br/> 

i didn't even know that was even a thing, going to try right away

Comment: It looks so much better now, i can't thank you enough, my thessi will look much prettier with your tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\label` after LaTeX has generated a number; a `figure` environment, by itself, doesn't generate a number: it's `\caption` that does.

```
\documentclass[rascunho]{fei}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\nu_{\mathrm{max}} \propto T \Leftrightarrow \nu_{\mathrm{max}}=
\mathrm{Constante}_{2}\cdot T
\label{eq:nu-max}
\end{equation}
onde, para um corpo negro, a equação~(\ref{eq:nu-max})
vale \SI{2,898e-3}{\meter\kelvin}.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\caption{Esta é uma legenda}
\label{fig:example}

\end{figure}

O gráfico (A) de figura~\ref{fig:example} mostra a distribuição de Boltzmann.

\end{document}
```

Now the reference can work.

[image]

Some other points. The (low) period is never used to denote multiplication. Textual inserts in a math formula should be upright. For the constant and in other similar instances, it's best to use `siunitx` that guarantees uniform appearance across the document (for instance, the symbol for kelvin is an uppercase K). If you prefer to have explicit multiplication symbols between units, change the `\sisetup` command in the preamble into

```
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
}
```

and the output would become

[image]

with *no* change in the document code.

Use a tie between the word “equação” as well as “figura” and the reference number.

It's incorrect to use `\center`; rather use `\centering` or nothing at all, as the class sets left aligned captions, so probably left aligned images are better suited.

Comment: Utterly perfect, thank you sensei. Sorry for the huge ammount of mistakes, i began using  latex just a few days ago

Comment: @LucasSalgueiro Don't worry: being a novice you're *supposed* not to know how to use the program. `;-)` Glad to be helpful.